# Cannot start ubuntu 12.04: URGENT

Tags: 12.04, boot, internet, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am haveing problems with my 3g USB internet stick (HSUPA MF195). I tried everything and I just cannot get it working. The last thing I tried to do is described here

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Connect-the-ZTE-MF636DB-USB-Modem-on-Ubuntu-158663.shtml

I have to the second part:

"Save and close the text file. Just in case, reboot your machine! "

After that I cannot start my os anymore. I just get Ubuntu and the pinkish start screen and that is it. I have some important data on it.   Me return everything back to normal!

UPDATE:

I managed to enter terminal and get to /etc/udev/rules.d/  but I cannot delete ZTEMF195. Rules file!

I tried changing the permissions, changing the content, forcing the delete but I get that it is read-only file and that it cannot be deleted?

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/ZTEMF637.rules` doesn't work? What's the exact error message?

Comment: the reason why it won't work is because i am in recovery mode where filesystem state: is read-only   this was the only way to get to terminal.
I get rm:cannot remove'ZTEMF637.rules': Read-only file system

Comment: Try this command: `mount -o rw,remount /`. According to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870817 , it should give you write access. If it fails, you can always use a live CD.

Comment: This Ubuntu wiki page also refers that: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode .

Comment: thank you it worked. noe all i need to figure out how to make my usb internet running

Comment: No problem. And good look with that! I'll post an answer for you to accept, so this is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the recovery mode may be used to recover the system.

But, according to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), the file system is mounted as read-only in recovery mode.
To re-mount it as read/write, run the following command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now you should be able to edit/delete files.

Also, you can always boot from a Live CD and use it to recover the system.